# determine input element status

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem determining status of an input field. I want JS to determine whether it is disabled or enabled but my code below always return 'false'. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
   <input name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$RobinBodyPlaceHolder   $LoggedInBodyPlaceHolder$AddEditUser1$EmailTextBox" type="text" value="email@mail.com"    id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_RobinBodyPlaceHolder_LoggedInBodyPlaceHolder_AddEditUser1_EmailTextBox"    class="EmailTextBox" disabled="disabled"/>


function ConfirmEmailChange() {
    alert($('.EmailTextBox').disabled==true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the `disabled` property of a jQuery object (I'm assuming it's jQuery, but it could be some other JS library using the `$` character), but jQuery objects don't have a `disabled` property.

If it is jQuery, you can access the actual DOM node contained within the jQuery object using array notation:

```
alert($('.EmailTextBox')[0].disabled);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `get` method:

```
alert($('.EmailTextBox').get(0).disabled);
```

Or, as others have shown, you can use the jQuery `prop` method. Notice that I've removed the `== true` part, as `disabled` is a boolean property and will return `true` or `false` anyway.

Comment: oops, yes it is jQuery. Thank you

Comment: In that case, you can use any of the methods given to you in these answers! I've added the jQuery tag to your question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't tagged jQuery, but since you seem to be using it, you can do this:

```
alert($('.EmailTextBox').is(':disabled'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/gwhrw/)**

```
function ConfirmEmailChange() {
    alert($('.EmailTextBox').prop('disabled'));
}
```

Just change it to check the disabled property this way. You were trying to access `.disabled` which isn't a valid jQuery property.